# Customize appearance of emacs markdown-mode

Tags: emacs, markdown, customization, r-markdown

I would like to change the background color of emacs markdown-mode, but only the code sections, mainly because I want them to be easily distinguishable from the rest. I have looked through some colorthemes but can't seem to find the right variable to do this.

I am using the colortheme package with a slightly modified version on 'Andreas' theme. For markdown I'm using markdown-mode and polymode (for Rmd).

Here is a demo Rmd

````
---
title: "Demo"
author: "me"
date: "08.09.17"
---

# Title

Here is some text. This is inline code `paste("Hello world")`. This is
a code block:

```{r this should be dark gray}
head(iris)
```

And thats it.
````

The question is, how to customize polymode. It lightens the background slightly for the code chunks.

This, I believe, is the relevant part of  `polymode-methods.el`:

```
(defun pm--get-adjusted-background (prop)
  ;; if > lighten on dark backgroun. Oposite on light.
  (color-lighten-name (face-background 'default)
                      (if (eq (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode) 'light)
                          (- prop) ;; darken
                    prop)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the faces you want to customize are `markdown-pre-face` (for indented code blocks) and `markdown-inline-code-face` (for inline code).

Both of these faces can be changed via `customize-face` if you so choose.

You can figure this out for yourself if you put your cursor inside a code block and run `M-x describe-face`.  The default choice is for the face the cursor is on.

Comment: When I do M-x customize-face in a code block the default is 'all faces'. This is what I don't understand. Modifieing inline code parts worked ok, but code blocks not.

Comment: Sorry I meant "describe-face" in that last paragraph, not "customize-face". I'll update the answer.

Comment: it still says 'default' even though my cursor is in the code block.

Comment: Can you pastebin an example markdown file?  Do you have a blank line between the code block and other text above it?  If there isn't a blank line between regular text and the code block the highlighting doesn't appear to work.  I'm not sure if that's valid markdown or not.

Comment: Edit: ignore my last comment.  Plain `markdown-mode` does support fenced code blocks.  In fact, your example works perfectly fine for me.  It does use a different face though: `markdown-language-keyword-face`.  See here: http://imgur.com/a/5cAqA

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I dont know what I am doing wrong. http://imgur.com/a/QXmcd

Comment: @R.Bobby, I think you're using [`polymode`](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode), not `markdown-mode`?

Comment: @Chris Well, I think I need polymode for Rmd, don't I? The major mode is markdown mode.

Comment: @R.Bobby, I don't fully understand how faces are handled in `polymode`. It looks like backgrounds are made relatively lighter or darker compared with the containing mode, but I can't figure out how to adjust the difference. (Your screenshot does show a slightly darker background in the R section, but it's a very slight change.)

Comment: me neither. I've looked through the documentation and edited my question again. Unfortunately, my lisp knowledge is pretty much non existent.

Comment: At this point you might wanna take this to the polymode maintainers.  It seems polymode doesn't preserve the faces of markdown-mode.  Since the code block is using the face "default", you aren't going to be able to customize just that without changing all text with the default face unless polymode provides such a mechanism.